# Error: forward declaration of ‘class SActionPrivate’ when using PIMPL

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, pimpl-idiom, moc

In Qt-program I realized the Pimpl approach, have 3 files

```
saction.cpp

saction.h

saction_p.h - with a private class sactionPrivate
```

The code is based on a code from kdelibs. I'm using CMAKE as a build system. So I get an error when compiling

*build/moc_saction.cpp:73:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class SActionPrivate’
actions/saction.h:492:18: error: forward declaration of ‘class SActionPrivate’*

The problem is in the file **moc_saction.cpp**, it doesn't include the file **saction_p.h**, only **saction.h**

so I need manually add the line in the generated moc-file:

```
#include "../actions/saction_p.h"
```

What should I do, in order not to manually correct the moc-file???

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(scalc)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)

include_directories(
${QT_INCLUDES} 
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/actions
)

set(scalc_SRCS 

actions/saction.cpp

main.cpp )

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

add_executable(scalc ${scalc_SRCS} )

target_link_libraries(scalc ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY}  ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY})
install(TARGETS scalc RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

**actions/saction.h**

```
#ifndef SACTION_H
#define SACTION_H

#include <QtGui/QWidgetAction>

class SAction : public QWidgetAction
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit SAction(QObject *parent);
        virtual ~SAction();

    private:
        friend class SActionPrivate;
        class SActionPrivate* const d;
        Q_PRIVATE_SLOT(d, void slotTriggered())
};


#endif
```

**actions/saction_p.h**

```
#ifndef SACTION_P_H
#define SACTION_P_H

class SAction;


class SActionPrivate
{
    public:

        SActionPrivate():q(0)
        {
        }

        void slotTriggered();

        void init(SAction *q_ptr);

        SAction *q;

};

#endif
```

**actions/saction.cpp**

```
#include "saction.h"
#include "saction_p.h"

#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QHBoxLayout>
#include <QtGui/QShortcutEvent>
#include <QtGui/QToolBar>

void SActionPrivate::init(SAction *q_ptr)
{
  q = q_ptr;

  QObject::connect(q, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), q,     SLOT(slotTriggered()));

    q->setProperty("isShortcutConfigurable", true);
}


void SActionPrivate::slotTriggered()
{}

SAction::SAction(QObject *parent)
    : QWidgetAction(parent), d(new SActionPrivate)
{
    d->init(this);
}

SAction::~SAction()
{
    delete d;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "saction.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SAction gg(new QWidget());
}
```

**generated by cmake moc_saction.cpp**

```
#include "../actions/saction.h"
#if !defined(Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION)
#error "The header file 'kaction.h' doesn't include <QObject>."
#elif Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION != 63
#error "This file was generated using the moc from 4.8.6. It"
#error "cannot be used with the include files from this version of Qt."
#error "(The moc has changed too much.)"
#endif

QT_BEGIN_MOC_NAMESPACE
static const uint qt_meta_data_SAction[] = {

// content:
  6,       // revision
  0,       // classname
  0,    0, // classinfo
  1,   14, // methods
  0,    0, // properties
  0,    0, // enums/sets
  0,    0, // constructors
  0,       // flags
  0,       // signalCount

// slots: signature, parameters, type, tag, flags
  9,    8,    8,    8, 0x08,

  0        // eod
};

static const char qt_meta_stringdata_SAction[] = {
"SAction\0\0slotTriggered()\0"
};

void SAction::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
    Q_ASSERT(staticMetaObject.cast(_o));
    SAction *_t = static_cast<SAction *>(_o);
    switch (_id) {
    case 0: _t->d->slotTriggered(); break;
    default: ;
    }
}
Q_UNUSED(_a);
}

const QMetaObjectExtraData SAction::staticMetaObjectExtraData = {
0,  qt_static_metacall 
};

const QMetaObject SAction::staticMetaObject = {
{ &QWidgetAction::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_SAction,
  qt_meta_data_SAction, &staticMetaObjectExtraData }
};

#ifdef Q_NO_DATA_RELOCATION
const QMetaObject &SAction::getStaticMetaObject() { return staticMetaObject; }
#endif //Q_NO_DATA_RELOCATION

const QMetaObject *SAction::metaObject() const
{
return QObject::d_ptr->metaObject ? QObject::d_ptr->metaObject : &staticMetaObject;
}

void *SAction::qt_metacast(const char *_clname)
{
if (!_clname) return 0;
if (!strcmp(_clname, qt_meta_stringdata_SAction))
    return static_cast<void*>(const_cast< SAction*>(this));
return QWidgetAction::qt_metacast(_clname);
}

int SAction::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
_id = QWidgetAction::qt_metacall(_c, _id, _a);
if (_id < 0)
    return _id;
if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
    if (_id < 1)
    qt_static_metacall(this, _c, _id, _a);
    _id -= 1;
}
return _id;
}
QT_END_MOC_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: This does not make any sense. You use pimpl in an application, not library??

Comment: Where and how do you use `SActionPrivate` in `saction.h`?

Comment: @SimonWarta: based on the error, it is forward declared in the header, which looks to be correct.

Comment: @lpapp jap, right. And I ask myself: why is forward declared not sufficient for the moc file. Maybe the `SActionPrivate` is involved in some signal/slot party?

Comment: No idea, I lost the track at pimpl in an application. I did not even continue with asking for an SSCCE... :)

Comment: Sorry guys, I added source code in the 1st post. I simply thought, that this is a common problem. -__-

Comment: Where is your `main.cpp`, still??

Comment: `add_executable(sdetailcalc ${scalc_SRCS} )` -> that looks wrong, still. Can you please make sure what you paste is working by running it yourself? It seems that we are your proof readers as you do not try these out yourself.

Comment: of course I don't look at you as proof readers, corrected Cmake -__-

Comment: `explicit SAction(QObject *parent);` -> Where is the public keyword? Can you please stop for a second and try to copy/paste these files into a new directory and then try to build it? It is very broken. It should not be our duty to do this.

Comment: yeah, sorry, i forgot to correct the post -__- =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, you have two issues in here:

- Missing includepath for the cmake binary directory where moc is generated

  ```
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
  ```
- You need to include the moc file at the end of your corresponding source file

  ```
  #include "moc_saction.cpp"
  ```